# Are (original) posts expected to be in English?

Tags: support, asking-questions

It doesn't specify this anywhere on the Tour page and I cannot find a meta question that directly answers this question (if one exists, please direct me there). Are questions on SE (and *nix.SE in particular) expected to be in English? If so, is there a reason that "Not in English" is not a flag option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this meta post on the topic. Yes only English is allowed. If posts are in anything other than English they should be either translated by the OP or closed/deleted.

- [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

*excerpted the highest UV'd answer there -

> The Stack Overflow Trilogy has an [official policy on non-English questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/):
>
> It is not, nor has it ever been, our goal to be the one place in the
>   world for all programming information in every possible human
>   language.
>
> > Direct question posters to native language resources. It is not the
> >     community's goal to teach English. The question asker should put some
> >     effort into the question. As long as the question is in salvageable
> >     English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and
> >     improved like any other post.

Comment: Good find! Is there a reason why there is no option to specify "Not in English" as a reason for flagging?

Comment: @HalosGhost - Probably b/c it doesn't come up that frequently enough to warrant it. Also you can use the other and provide a custom reason if needed.

Comment: Okay. I've seen several posts now not in-English (certainly not many though). And, so far, I've simply used the custom reason. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @HalosGhost - yup, keep doing that, when I seem them I delete them if I cannot salvage.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking?

Comment: @CanadianLuke, I feel like the question was well-resolved. What do you feel is unclear?

Comment: That's what I flag non-Englishquestions with

Comment: On the few that I've seen, I run them through Google Translate.  If I can't fix it after that I'll usually close with a custom reason, as slm recommends.