# Do we have a list of rules?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing new answers, I came across one in Spanish. I assume that English is the only allowed language.

The problem is that I can't find that written anywhere. The [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) has some guidance for [asking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking)/[answering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/answering) questions, but none of these posts describe any rules about language.

Another example is our rule about posting `<pre>` text instead of terminal screenshots.  I know it's a rule because I've seen senior members enforcing it, but I can't find that in the help center.

It doesn't seem right to enforce rules that we only assume exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the rules aren't in the Help Center. There could be several reasons for that, e.g. the rule that answers may not be in Spanish does not apply to [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) but it has the same Help Center articles as all other sites in the network.

Most rules, including the reasons why they are as they are, can be found on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). The ones you're looking for are:

- [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/295232)
- [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/295232)

Some of these rules have their own post on Unix & Linux Meta as well:

- [Are (original) posts expected to be in English?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/111051)
- [PSA: Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408) (thanks @Scott)

Comment: Thanks,  I was hoping there was a more consolidated way than getting/staying familiar with the entire meta site.

Comment: @stewart sadly, there isn't. And it's a pain, yes, but it's what you get when the rules are sort of figured out by the community as we go along. When in doubt, search meta here, and https://meta.stackexchange.com or post a question as you did. You can also try in chat.

Comment: @terdon, also, if SE cared, it could make the help pages editable per-site, by the site moderators, which would deal nicely with the "figured out by the community" part...

Comment: @ilkkachu the moderators can edit https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and parts of the [tour]. The problem with making all pages editable is that it's a pain to merge future changes in the template. Maybe not for one site, but if all 170+ sites in the network would make changes on their own site...

Comment: @Glorfindel, oh yes, the merging would be a pain... But in any case, there doesn't seem to be much space for site-specific guides in the Ask a question view. If I open it from a non-logged-in browser, I get a [small popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuH7r.png) with minimal guidance on asking a question in general, and then there's a link to https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask in the sidebar. I can't even see a link to https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic anywhere... Let alone something where we could add even "Please don't post images of text, and do use code formatting".

Comment: (and yes, I was talking about the help pages at first, but then it just occurred to me to look at what the Ask a question page actually looks like)

Comment: @ilkkachu According to the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/410681) of its new version, the ask page has some room for customization. It would make sense to create a U&L Meta post to discuss it.